# Return object from HashMap using Iterator

Tags: java, object, iterator, hashmap

`roomCharacters` is a `HashMap` of keys and values (`String` keys and `Character` objects).

I need to return a Character from the collection. I have used an Iterator to simply return the first Character it finds, when the method is called.

```
public Character getCharacter()
{
    Iterator<HashMap.Entry<String, Character>> it = roomCharacters.entrySet().iterator();
    if (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        return pair.getValue();
    }        
}
```

But it fails to compile:

```
  incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Character
```

Clearly I've misunderstood something or missed a step. Please advise and explain where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your pair variable with the correct type parameters, it will work, and you can get rid of the extra cast:

```
    HashMap.Entry<String,Character> pair = it.next();
```

Comment: @AK83 please press the green checkmark if the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the generics specification in the definition of `pair`. Additionally, since `it` is specified using generics, note that you don't need to cast when assigning its `next` to `pair`:

```
public Character getCharacter()
{
    Iterator<HashMap.Entry<String, Character>> it = roomCharacters.entrySet().iterator();
    if (it.hasNext())
    {
        HashMap.Entry<String, Character> pair = it.next();
        return pair.getValue();
    }        
}
```